# Printing in iOS from Swift in XCode 6 beta 7

Tags: ios, swift, airprint

Here is the code I use for Swift airprinting with beta 6 and it worked fine:

```
@IBAction func button3Tapped() {
    var pic:UIPrintInteractionController = .sharedPrintController()
    var viewpf:UIViewPrintFormatter = myTextView.viewPrintFormatter()
    pic.delegate = self
    pic.showsPageRange = true
    pic.printFormatter = viewpf
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        pic.presentFromRect(self.myButton3.frame, inView:self.view, animated:true, completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        pic.presentAnimated(true, completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Of course, beta 7 broke it with a "Value of optional type 'UIPrintInteractionController' not unwrapped; did you mean to use ! or ??" on the first var line.  Unfortunately the XCode suggested fix doesn't fix it, and I'm not smart enough to figure it out myself!

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 6 beta 7 audited much of the Cocoa Touch API for how it exposes **optional values** – that is, those that could possibly be nil. It looks like the shared print controller is one such value. Opening the Swift version of the header for UIPrintInteractionController, I see:

```
class func sharedPrintController() -> UIPrintInteractionController?
```

The type with a trailing question mark – `UIPrintInteractionController?` – indicates that the return value of `sharedPrintController()` could be an instance of UIPrintInteractionController or it could be nil.

If you are confident that, in the situation you call that method, it will always return a non-nil value, you can immediately force this optional value to "unwrap" into an instance of UIPrintInteractionController:

```
var pic = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()!
// the rest of your code
```

On the other hand, if you think you might ever get nil from that method, you can use Swift's **optional binding** syntax to check that case and continue using `pic` only if it is non-nil:

```
if let pic = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController() {
    // the rest of your code
}
```

Either way, Xcode is telling you that you now need to deal with the fact that the shared print controller is exposed as an optional value in beta 7.